# Autofac and SignalR in Webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, signalr, autofac

I try to inject my service in Hub by Autofac, I didn't success.
I used this autofac doc: http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/signalr.html

**AdminHub code:**

```
public class AdminHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IUserSerivce _userService;

    public AdminHub(IUserSerivce userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
```

**Bootstrapper code:**

```
public class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        SetAutofacContainerWebApi();
        SetAutofacContainerSignalR();
    }

    private static void SetAutofacContainerWebApi()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Get your HttpConfiguration.
        var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

        // Register your Web API controllers.
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>().As<IDbFactory>().InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(BondService).Assembly).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service")).AsImplementedInterfaces();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(BondRepository).Assembly).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository")).AsImplementedInterfaces();

        // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
        var container = builder.Build();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }

    private static void SetAutofacContainerSignalR()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Register your SignalR hubs.
        builder.RegisterHubs(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>().As<IDbFactory>().InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(UserService).Assembly).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service")).AsImplementedInterfaces();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(UserRepository).Assembly).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository")).AsImplementedInterfaces();

        // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
        var container = builder.Build();
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
```

**Global.asax code:**

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        App_Start.Bootstrapper.Run();
    }
}
```

**Startup code:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { };
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
    }
}
```

**UserService code:**

```
public interface IUserService
{
    bool UpdateUser(int UserID, string ConnectionID);
}
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _repository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public UserService(IUserRepository repository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public bool UpdateUser(int UserID, string ConnectionID)
    {
        try
        {
            var EFUser = _repository.GetById(UserID);

            if (EFUser != null)
            {
                if (EFUser.ConnectionID != ConnectionID)
                {
                    EFUser.ConnectionID = ConnectionID;
                }
            }
            EFUser.ConnectionID = ConnectionID;

            _unitOfWork.Commit();

            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to inject the service in my Hub? The debbug doesn't enter to `AdminHub` function, If I delete the userService from `public AdminHub(IUserSerivce userService)` so everything is ok and I see the debbug.

Comment: You're setting GlobalHost.DependencyResolver....but HubConfiguration has a property for DependencyResolver as well. Have you tried setting the resolver there instead?

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: HubConfiguration takes an IDependencyResolver. Try assigning it the `AutofacDependencyResolver`

Comment: Thank you, but no change

Comment: Does `UserService` implement `IUserSerivce`? What is the error message you receive?

Comment: Yes, I edit the post with UserService code. I don't get an error.